# Error while executing PowerShell script using SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server-agent, powershell

I am executing a PowerShell script using SQL Server Agent job, script code is given below(it is added as is in the Job step 1) :

```
$OriginFile = "\\vmpr-file1\share3\RT-BI_Shared\ABC.xlsx"
$SourceFile = "\\AZSDV-SSRS1\DASHFiles\ABC.xlsx"
$sCSVFile   = "\\AZSDV-SSRS1\DASHFiles\ABC.csv"
$OrigFileExists = Test-Path $OriginFile
$CSVFileExists = Test-Path $sCSVFile

If ($OrigFileExists -eq $True)
{      
    # Move latest excel file Base to Source Location
    Move-item –path $OriginFile –destination $SourceFile -Force
    # If CSV file exists at Source Location, delete it and convert Excel to CSV format
    if ($CSVFileExists -eq $True)
    {
        Remove-item -path $sCSVFile
    }
    # Convert excel file to CSV format
    # Get COM Object
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
    $ExcelDoc = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($SourceFile)
    $Worksheet = $ExcelDoc.Worksheets.item(1)
    $ExcelDoc.SaveAs($sCSVFile ,[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlCSVWindows)
    $ExcelDoc.Close($false)
    $Excel.Quit()
}
Else
{
    Exit
}
```

SQL Server Job is being executed using SQL Admin role, but I am getting below error when executing the job :

**The process could not be created for step 1 of job 0xF7D5C86B5CB7AC4885A7639124BA5E7A (reason: The system cannot find the file specified).  The step failed.**

The error message is very generic unable to find out the issue, can someone help resolving this error.

Comment: Please add line feeds to your errorlog text

Comment: Two questions: Does the Powershell script work if you run it under your login, and does the account used to execute the job have access to read and/or write to the locations specified in the Powershell script?

Comment: Hi Stephen, I changed the Job type to Powershell from CMDEXEC, now the job is getting executed successfully but without performing desired activities - **Message
Executed as user: PMCI\SVC_DASH_SQLDevAGT. The step did not generate any output.  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.** How to check that specific userid has read/write permissions at the shared locations. The script is running fine when executed from PowerShell ISE but doing nothing when executed through SQL server agent and also not showing any error.

Comment: Does your login have access to view the files in the locations shown at the top of the Powershell script? If so, right-click on each folder, select Properties, then Security, and see if PMCI\SVC_DASH_SQLDevAGT has permissions to read the contents of the folders. The message you received makes sense. I suspect the service account doesn't have permissions to the location in $OriginFile, so in the Else branch, put throw("Not True"), and you SHOULD see that.

Comment: Are you executing this from a Powershell job step, or a CmdExec job step which calls powershell.exe? Also, is there any connection back to SQL Server in this job, or are you using Agent as a generic task scheduler to run this?

Comment: @Stephen Falken - Checked access at Read & Write locations in script. Appropriate access (Read & Execute) is granted to UserId : SVC_DASH_SQLDevAGT, still the job gets executed successfully but without performing desired activities. Log mentions below message :
- Message Executed as user: PMCI\SVC_DASH_SQLDevAGT. The step did not generate any output. Process Exit Code 0. The step succeeded.

Comment: @alroc - The job is executed from a Powershell job step. Would you please elaborate what is meant by your second question on connection back to SQL Server or using agent as generic task scheduler ?

Comment: @RachnaVerma the PowerShell job step is very limited and doesn't work well. Switch to `CmdExec` and run `powershell.exe` following the guide at https://dbatools.io/agent . As for my second question, what I'm getting at is "does your job interact with SQL Server (querying tables, running backups, whatever) or are you just using it as a way to run completely unrelated processes?"

Comment: @alroc - My job does not interact with SQL Server, it reads an Excel file and copies it in CSV format at another location. I need to use SQL server agent just for scheduling the job so that I is triggered and run daily.

Comment: @RachnaVerma there are other ways to execute scheduled processes, such as Task Scheduler. Don't expend SQL Server resources (licensing costs money) on non-SQL Server tasks which will run with the same permissions as SQL Agent (which may present a security concern). Set up your task on a "utility" server, running under a regular job scheduler, under an account with the proper permissions. Talk to your sysadmins about the options available.

Comment: @alroc - My manager is not agreeing for TS. Script is giving below error
Executed as user: @@@@. A job step received an error at line 18 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is '$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application  '. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).  '.  Process Exit Code -1.  The step failed.

Comment: Any idea what can be the reason for this error as at the same location I am able to execute below command using SQL server agent job: Write-Output "End of Script" > C:\aaaaa\FirstOP_RV.xlsx. As a result of this command excel gets generated but when I try to open it, it throws message - **Cannot open the file, file format or file extension is not valid. Verify file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.**

Comment: What is their objection to using Task Scheduler? It's a more appropriate tool for the job. Further, you shouldn't have MS Office apps installed **on your SQL Server** at all. It's a security concern, additional licensing footprint, and there is no need for it to be there otherwise (if you _must_ manipulate Excel files, look at the `ImportExcel` PowerShell module). The whole approach of using Agent to run a PowerShell script to manipulate Excel files is misguided from the outset. Using Agent for this is a waste of resources and adding unnecessary complexity to the process